# Multi socket vs Single socket for game server clients?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I'm currently building a poker game server with C#.Server will contain single saloon and multiple tables.I want clients can be on multiple tables at the same time.If I use single socket for a client, server must parse table messages with tableId, on the other hand if I use multiple socket for a client per table parsing at server side will be much easier. Shoul i use single socket per client or multiple sockets per table?

Comment: See my comment at another posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62661036/connecting-to-tcp-server-running-in-uwp-app#comment110811482_62661036

Comment: @jdweng i just read your comment and 100% aggre with you but I'm asking which option is more suitable?

Comment: There is really not much of a difference.  You have to design you application layer and then figure out when connection method works best with the application.